# unable to create file server.php permision denied

Tags: laravel, git, github

Estoy retomando un antiguo proyecto en Laravel y cuando procedo a clonar el repositorio me trae todo pero me salta el siguiente error en la consola:

> error: unable to create file MyFuture/server.php: Permission denied

Cuando corro php artisan serve e ingreso al puerto de localhost, el navegador se encuentra en blanco con el siguiente error.

> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\Proyectos\grupo6-redSocialLaravel\MyFuture\server.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

No se como solucionarlo, intente haciendo lo siguiente:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan key:generate
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar.

Espero que alguno pueda ayudarme.

Comment: O sea... ese error `error: unable to create file MyFuture/server.php: Permission denied` ¿te sale al hacer `git clone tu-proyecto` o en qué momento?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ exactamente me sale al hacer git clone de un proyecto

Comment: Ok, no parece tanto un problema de laravel, sino de permisos del sistema operativo y git. Le agregué un par de etiquetas para que vean tu pregunta los usuarios que entienden más sobre esos temas.